# a PowerShell script should use the template txt file to read info and dynamically generate the email based on that info

Tags: powershell, text-files

1. The PowerShell script should use the template and dynamically generate the email
2. The ps scripts should be able to replace the variables with the values passed during the script execution
   Some of the values should be read from the control file and some from the parameters passed while executing the script

Sample Control file:

Email: 1

From: user1

To: several users

Subject: Going to start patching   - Start Time

Content: c:\folder\email_template1.txt

Variable1: sysdate

Variable2: hostname

here is my code but does not send the emails to multiple email addresses and multiple lines in body content:

```
$Subject = "Going to Start Patching " + $patchName + " Start Time:" + $startTime
$Content = "C:\Users\Documents\participants2.txt"
$From = (Select-String -Path $Content -Pattern "From:(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value
$To = (Select-String -Path $Content -Pattern "To:(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value 
$Body = (Select-String -Path $Content -Pattern "Body:(.*)").Matches.Groups[1].Value|
    ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace 'patchname', $patchName}
$patchName = [System.NET.DNS]::GetHostByName('')
$startTime = Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K"
$SMTPServer = ""
Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Cc $Cc -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Subject $Subject -Body $Body
```

Comment: There are 2 things to point out, 1. You're using variables __before they're assigned__, ergo they're null (`$patchName` and `$startTime`). 2. `$Body` is assigned from the value of the matched pattern `Body:(.*)`, however, __there is no Body:__ on your Sample Control file.

Comment: Thanks, buddy right, in the text file that I have on my pc I changed the content to body cause the file's name was content, but thanks for the point No1